# Extracting data values from the ifft signal

Tags: python, fft, complex-numbers

How to extract the `values` of the `filtered signal` from `Fourier transformation`? As `ifft` returns a complex number which is hard to for further calculations.

My python code:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create a simple signal with two frequencies
dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0,1,dt)
f = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*120*t) # Sum of 2 frequencies
f_clean = f
noise = 2.5*np.random.randn(len(t))
f = f + noise              # Add some noise

## Compute the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)

n = len(t)
fhat = np.fft.fft(f,n)                     # Compute the FFT
PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n             # Power spectrum (power per freq)
freq = (1/(dt*n)) * np.arange(n)           # Create x-axis of frequencies in Hz
L = np.arange(1,np.floor(n/2),dtype='int') # Only plot the first half of freqs

## Use the PSD to filter out noise
indices = PSD > 100       # Find all freqs with large power
PSDclean = PSD * indices  # Zero out all others
fhat = indices * fhat     # Zero out small Fourier coeffs. in Y
ffilt = np.fft.ifft(fhat) # Inverse FFT for filtered time signal
```

Here `ffilt` is the filtered signal which returns a `complex number`. I want to use this signal for mathematical computation but not sure on the process of extracting the values.

Comment: Depends on what computation you want to do.  `np.abs()` will convert this to a real signal.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the suggestion, this does help, however all the values are converted to `positive` which changes the scale of the signal.  Is there any way to keep the `negative real values` of the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can see how to acquire real values from a complex number, specifically its real and imaginary parts, and its magnitude.

```
a = ffilt[10]
# (1.09200370931126+4.0997278010904346e-17j)

# Get real part    
a.real
# 1.09200370931126

# Get imaginary part
a.imag
# 4.0997278010904346e-17
    
# Get magnitude 
abs(a)
# 1.09200370931126 
# (the imaginary part is close to zero, so the magnitude 
# is almost equal to the real part)
```

You can do the above for the whole array.

```
ffilt.real
ffilt.imag
abs(ffilt)
    
# Bonus: phase
np.angle(ffilt)
```

I don't know what your next calculations will be, but you *probably* want to use the magnitude (abs).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am using the `filtered signal` for interpolation. The `abs()` method changes the scale making everything to be positive. 
How can i keep it within original scale?

Comment: You can't, magnitude is always positive `sqrt(REAL^2 + IMG^2)`.

Comment: Furthermore, the real and imaginary parts usually don't tell you anything useful. Most of the times, I think that abs() and phase are used.

Comment: I also included the phase.